# javascript: shuffle 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to shuffle a 2D array in javascript ?

I need my 2D array to be shuffled after being created.

will this be a good solution of doing this?

thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i shuffle an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that once for a Tile Map in a 2D Game.

```
for (let i = 0; i < mapSizeY; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapSizeX; j++) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;
        map[i][j] = rand;
    }
}
```

This generated a random Number between 0 and 3 for each tile

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash. It's javascript lib for array manipulation.

You can shuffle with lodash:

```
_.shuffle(yourArray);
```

https://lodash.com/docs#shuffle